# How could I interpret $\delta$ in $\mathbf{R} \in \mathbb{R}^{|S|}/\delta$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms

I'm trying to implement a Paper and when looking at the pseudocode I encountered the following:

1. Pick a random reward vector $\mathbf{R} \in \mathbb{R}^{|S|}/\delta$
2. ...
3. Repeat:

   - Pick a reward vector $\tilde{\mathbf{R}}$ uniformly at random from the neighbours of $\mathbf{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{|S|}/\delta$
   - ...

Suppose e.g. $\delta = 0.05$ and $|S| = 5$.
What's the meaning of "$/\delta$" and how could I implement such sampling in code? I understood it has something to do with the [Equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) but couldn't figure out how to apply this concept in practice.

The Paper I am referring to is [Bayesian Inverse Reinforcement Learning](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/IJCAI/2007/IJCAI07-416.pdf), the pseudocode appears in Figure 3 specifically. [Here](https://github.com/uidilr/bayesian_irl/blob/master/src/birl.py) we can find a (possibly incorrect) implementation:

```
def sample_random_rewards(n_states, step_size, r_max):
    """
    sample random rewards form gridpoint(R^{n_states}/step_size).
    :param n_states:
    :param step_size:
    :param r_max:
    :return: sampled rewards
    """
    rewards = np.random.uniform(low=-r_max, high=r_max, size=n_states)
    # move these random rewards toward a gridpoint
    # add r_max to make mod to be always positive
    # add step_size for easier clipping
    rewards = rewards + r_max + step_size
    for i, reward in enumerate(rewards):
        mod = reward % step_size
        rewards[i] = reward - mod
    # subtracts added values from rewards
    rewards = rewards - (r_max + step_size)
```

Thanks

Comment: I do not see how the notation $\mathbb{R}^{|S|}/\delta$ is associated with a set of equivalence classes if $\delta$ is a real number (e.g. $0.05$ as you put). Are you sure this is what is meant?

Comment: Yes I am pretty confused too, by the way I linked the paper and a possible implementation in the question.

Comment: The definition of $\mathbb{R}^{|S|}/\delta$ is given at the beginning of section 5: "the intersection points of a
grid of length $\delta$ in the region $\mathbb{R}^{|S|}$ (denoted $\mathbb{R}^{|S|}/\delta$)."

Comment: Now everything is clear, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @johnny10 has mentioned in the comments, there is a definition at the beginning of section 5:

> The sampling technique we use is an MCMC algorithm `GridWalk` (see [Vempala, 2005]) that generates a Markov chain on the intersection points of a grid of length $\delta$ in the region $\mathbb R^{|S|}$ (denoted $\mathbb R^{|S|}/\delta$).

Hence, the paper is referring to the set of all $|S|$-tuples of real numbers, where each entry is an integer multiple of $\delta$. For $\delta = 0.05$ and $|S|=3$ one example would be $(23.45, -8.10, 5.55)$, since each of the three numbers is a multiple of $0.05$. Numbers like $1.23$ would not be allowed.

The chosen notation is non-standard and a better notation would be $(\delta\mathbb Z)^{|S|}$.